# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rename'

Tags: python, html, spyder, data-science, edx

```
df.rename(columns={'nan': 'RK', 'PP': 'PLAYER','SH':'TEAM','nan':'GP','nan':'G','nan':'A','nan':'PTS','nan':'+/-','nan':'PIM','nan':'PTS/G','nan':'SOG','nan':'PCT','nan':'GWG','nan':'PPG','nan':'PPA','nan':'SHG','nan':'SHA'}, inplace=True)
```

This is my code to rename the columns according to  http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/2015/seasontype/2

I want both the tables to have same column names. I am using python2 in spyder IDE.
When I run the code above, it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rename'
```

Comment: You should post your code. `df` is clearly a `list` and not a `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

The original question was posted a long time ago, but I just came across the same issue and found the solution here:  [pd.read_html() imports a list rather than a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710903/pd-read-html-imports-a-list-rather-than-a-dataframe)

When you do `pd.read_html` you are creating a list of dataframes since the website may have more than 1 table.  Add one more line of code before you try your rename:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
```

and then `df = dfs[0]` ; you will have the `df` variable as a dataframe , which will allow you to run the `df.rename` command you are trying to run in the original question.

Answer (score -2):

this should be able to fix , df is you dataset
df.columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f']