# pd.read_html() imports a list rather than a dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas

I used `pd.read_html()` to import a table from a webpage but instead of structuring the data as a dataframe Python imported it as a list.  How can I import the data as a dataframe?  Thank you!

The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

import html5lib

url = 'http://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html'

dfs = pd.read_html(url)

type(dfs)

Out[1]: list
```

Answer (score 24):

[`.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) produces a *list of dataframes* (there could be multiple tables in an HTML source), get the desired one by index. In your case, there is a single dataframe:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[0]
print(df)
```

Note that, if there are no `table`s in the HTML source, it would return an error and would never produce an empty list.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed df is a dataframe.  However when I tried the .head, .tail and .index parameters on df Python returned error messages.  How can I correct this?

Comment: @AlexanderKonstantinidis interesting, `df.tail`, `df.head`, `df.index` work for me. What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'heads',  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tails',  TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable

Comment: @AlexanderKonstantinidis ah, it is `tail`, `head` and `index` - no `s` prefix and no `()` (these are not methods).

Answer (score 9):

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
url = 'http://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df
```

Comment: this was helpful to me. solved the problem of scraping a table as a list, then converts that list into a dataframe