# keep getting error with multiple pages when using df to excel works fine with 1 page

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here is my code everything works pretty good until I try and send to excel.  I have a script that works fine for one web page but not multiple pages.

**Working code and what I want:**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter


dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/stat/yards-per-play/',header=0)
for df in dfs:
    print(df)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('nfl.xlsx')


df.to_excel('nflypp.xlsx', sheet_name='yppo', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')

writer.save()
```

**none working code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter


oyyp_df = pd.read_html('https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/stat/yards-per-play.html',header=0)
dyyp_df = pd.read_html('https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/stat/opponent-yards-per-play',header=0)
for df in (oyyp_df, dyyp_df):
    print(df)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('nfl.xlsx') 


df.to_excel('nflypp.xlsx', sheet_name='yppo', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel('nflypp.xlsx', sheet_name='yppd', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')


writer.save()
```

Working until it gets to the df.to_excel

```
error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

**Here is the out put**

C:\Cabs\projects>nflstatsypp.py
[    Rank           Team  2018  Last 3  Last 1  Home  Away  2017
0      1    Kansas City   7.0     7.0     6.9   6.4   7.5   6.1
1      2    LA Chargers   6.8     6.4     6.2   6.6   6.9   5.9
2      3        LA Rams   6.7     6.2     5.4   7.0   6.4   5.8
3      4      Tampa Bay   6.5     6.3     5.3   6.3   6.8   5.6
4      5    New Orleans   6.2     6.0     3.6   6.7   5.7   6.3
5      6     Pittsburgh   6.2     6.0     5.3   6.2   6.2   5.8
6      7       Carolina   6.2     7.3     6.8   6.1   6.2   5.1
7      8        Atlanta   6.0     5.0     2.9   6.5   5.5   5.8
8      9      Green Bay   6.0     5.4     4.4   5.9   6.1   4.9
9     10         Denver   5.9     6.1     6.3   6.1   5.8   4.8
10    11    New England   5.9     6.2     6.6   6.2   5.5   6.0
11    12      NY Giants   5.8     6.2     5.0   5.4   6.1   4.9
12    13        Houston   5.7     6.0     5.2   6.2   5.3   5.0
13    14        Seattle   5.7     6.2     6.8   5.5   5.9   5.2
14    15  San Francisco   5.7     5.8     6.1   5.4   5.9   5.3
15    16   Indianapolis   5.7     5.7     3.7   6.2   5.1   4.6
16    17     Cincinnati   5.6     5.1     4.8   5.5   5.7   4.8
17    18      Minnesota   5.6     5.1     4.7   5.6   5.6   5.4
18    19        Oakland   5.5     5.3     6.4   6.2   5.0   5.4
19    20   Philadelphia   5.5     5.4     6.1   5.5   5.5   5.6
20    21        Chicago   5.5     4.6     4.9   6.0   5.0   4.9
21    22      Cleveland   5.4     7.3     8.2   5.1   5.8   4.9
22    23      Tennessee   5.4     7.1     7.5   5.8   5.0   5.2
23    24          Miami   5.4     4.7     3.5   5.8   4.9   4.9
24    25         Dallas   5.3     5.2     4.7   5.6   5.1   5.3
25    26        Detroit   5.3     5.0     4.8   5.2   5.5   5.5
26    27      Baltimore   5.2     5.4     4.8   5.3   5.2   4.6
27    28     Washington   5.2     4.8     5.6   5.0   5.4   5.3
28    29   Jacksonville   5.0     4.3     3.8   5.0   5.1   5.4
29    30        NY Jets   4.9     4.5     4.3   5.4   4.4   5.0
30    31        Buffalo   4.5     6.2     6.3   4.5   4.6   4.7
31    32        Arizona   4.4     4.8     5.5   4.5   4.2   4.7]
[    Rank           Team  2018  Last 3  Last 1  Home  Away  2017
0      1      Baltimore   4.6     4.1     2.9   4.5   4.8   5.0
1      2        Buffalo   4.9     4.2     3.5   5.1   4.7   5.3
2      3        Chicago   4.9     4.8     5.0   4.6   5.2   5.1
3      4     Pittsburgh   5.2     5.1     6.2   5.6   4.8   5.3
4      5         Dallas   5.3     5.2     3.6   4.9   5.6   5.1
5      6      Minnesota   5.3     5.4     6.6   4.6   5.9   4.8
6      7        Arizona   5.3     5.1     4.4   5.0   5.6   4.9
7      8   Jacksonville   5.3     5.6     7.5   4.3   6.2   4.8
8      9        Houston   5.4     6.1     8.2   5.9   4.9   5.7
9     10      Tennessee   5.4     5.1     3.8   5.0   5.7   5.1
10    11    LA Chargers   5.5     5.1     5.3   5.7   5.4   5.3
11    12   Indianapolis   5.5     4.8     3.9   5.6   5.4   5.7
12    13      Green Bay   5.5     5.7     5.5   5.2   5.8   5.5
13    14  San Francisco   5.6     5.9     6.8   5.1   5.8   5.3
14    15    New England   5.7     5.4     4.7   5.4   5.9   5.7
15    16        NY Jets   5.7     6.8     6.7   6.0   5.4   5.4
16    17      Cleveland   5.7     5.3     5.2   6.0   5.5   5.1
17    18       Carolina   5.8     5.5     5.3   5.8   5.8   5.4
18    19     Washington   5.8     5.8     6.1   5.7   5.9   5.3
19    20      NY Giants   5.8     6.0     4.9   5.7   6.0   5.7
20    21         Denver   5.9     6.2     4.8   6.0   5.7   4.9
21    22    New Orleans   5.9     4.8     4.7   6.1   5.8   5.4
22    23    Kansas City   6.0     5.4     6.4   5.4   6.4   5.6
23    24   Philadelphia   6.1     7.0     5.6   5.7   6.6   5.2
24    25        Detroit   6.1     5.6     5.4   5.9   6.4   5.5
25    26        LA Rams   6.1     6.4     4.8   6.4   5.8   5.3
26    27        Seattle   6.1     7.2     6.1   6.7   5.8   4.9
27    28        Atlanta   6.2     5.1     4.8   6.4   5.9   5.2
28    29     Cincinnati   6.2     5.7     6.3   6.2   6.2   5.0
29    30          Miami   6.3     6.7     6.3   6.1   6.5   5.4
30    31      Tampa Bay   6.4     6.4     6.8   5.8   7.1   6.0
31    32        Oakland   6.6     6.2     6.9   6.5   6.6   5.6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Cabs\projects\nflstatsypp.py", line 14, in 
    df.to_excel('nflypp.xlsx', sheet_name='yppo', index=False,   engine='xlsxwriter')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

One last ? how do you clean up the above second table so the headers are lined up like the first table? if it has been answered add link please. Thanks. Note when printed out in python the first table headers are correct just for clarification.  thanks again.  no more edits.  hope all this helps.

I'm brand new, just having fun.  Have been researching for months with all different codes.  have about 15.py trying to get this to work.

Thanks for any help. if the answer is out there I can't find or understand it. :-)  finally.  again sorry for being such a newbe.  LOL

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me.  Do you understand what it says?

Comment: ok both codes are there in the proper format.  thanks for any help

Comment: does it have to be writen as dfs instead of df?  if so how do i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do this. I would probably loop it condense the code a bit, save each dataframe as you iterate in your `for` loop. But it also looks like you want different names for your sheets, which would involve creating a variable in same way to associate each of your `pd.read_html`s, and it appears you're a beginner, so we'll just try to keep this as simple as possible, and we'll do it another way which is just straight away save the data.

First off, when you do `oyyp_df = pd.read_html('https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/stat/yards-per-play.html',header=0)`, it's storing it as dataframe, BUT packaging it into a list (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710903/pd-read-html-imports-a-list-rather-than-a-dataframe)).

Also, it would be benificial to go back and read up about lists in Python. So your `for` loop iterates through those items in each of your lists (`oyyp_df, dyyp_df`).

If you want to call a specific item in a list, you call it by it's index/position. The key to note though, is that the index starts at 0. So the first item in a list is at position 0, the 2nd item is at position 1, etc.

`a_list = ['first item', 'sencond item, 'third item']`

to call that first item, you'd type `a_list[0]` and you would see the output 'first item'.

Now a list can be of many data types. It could be strings, like above, it can integers, it can be dictionaries, or in your case here, it's dataframes.

so `oyyp_df` is really = `[<your DATFRAME>, <maybe a 2nd dataframe>, etc.]`. yours only contains 1 item, in the first position. So you get that error. lists can't do `.to_excel`, but dataframes can.

What we can do is store that 1st item dataframe though by setting that equal to another name (or you could actually use the same name...but be careful as if your list has other items in it, you'd lose those); `oyyp_df = oyyp_df[0]`

I changed a couple things to hopefully make it clearer in your code below.

```
import pandas as pd


html_data1 = pd.read_html('https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/stat/yards-per-play.html',header=0)
html_data2 = pd.read_html('https://www.teamrankings.com/nfl/stat/opponent-yards-per-play',header=0)


for df in (html_data1, html_data2):
    print(df)


oyyp_df = html_data1[0]
dyyp_df = html_data2[0]


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('nflypp.xlsx')

oyyp_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='yppo', index=False)
dyyp_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='yppd', index=False)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: thank you that helped now for my second ?  I know I'm just missing something and just can't figure it out.  I need to add 6 more URLS.  Yikes!!!!

Comment: by the way the none working code has been added to original post for less confusion.  Thanks again.

Comment: hope the answer helps you get on your way. make sure to accept the answer if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: thank you for the complete and through explanation. will let you know how it goes. i have some reading to do.n

Comment: your code did exactly what I wanted.  Thanks now I need to understand so I can add on.Thanks again.