# pd.read_html cannot find packages which I have installed in pycharm how to get it to recognize them

Tags: python, python-venv

I am using pycharm community edition. I am trying to get python to read html using this function

data=pd.read_html('https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html')

I have installed lxml as requested but I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cc15522\OneDrive - University of 
Bristol\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 
1094, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)
  File "C:\Users\cc15522\OneDrive - University of 
Bristol\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 894, in _parse
    parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
  File "C:\Users\cc15522\OneDrive - University of 
Bristol\Documents\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 851, in _parser_dispatch
    raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
```

It is asking me to import lxml however I have already installed this and the files it claims it cannot find are in the locations specified.

Has anyone had a problem similar to this. I am doing this on my university's computer.

Solution: Turning the computer on and off seems to have made it recognize the package. Guess I should have tried that first before posting lol.

Comment: Check if you have installed it in a environment in which you are working.

Comment: Check this answer out could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710903/pd-read-html-imports-a-list-rather-than-a-dataframe