# Need to clean web scraped data using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to write a code for scraping data from http://goldpricez.com/gold/history/lkr/years-3. The code that I have written follows below. The code works and gives me my intended results.

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://goldpricez.com/gold/history/lkr/years-3"

df = pd.read_html(url)

print(df)
```

But result is with some unwanted data and I want only the data in the table. Please can some help me with this.

[Here I have added the image of the output with unwanted data (red circled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ODU5.png)

Comment: You can always slice the Data frame to get rid of the unwanted data. Alternatively, use Beautiful soup library to parse html before using pandas library.

Comment: ``read_html`` return list of dataframe for each table in HTML source, use list index to access the required dataframe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710903/pd-read-html-imports-a-list-rather-than-a-dataframe

Comment: You were correct to use `pd.read_html`. Just select the correct index where the data is [3]. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    import pandas as pd



   url = "http://goldpricez.com/gold/history/lkr/years-3"

   df = pd.read_html(url)# this will give you a list of dataframes from html

  print(df[3])
```

Comment: Thanks mate. it works fine and small question. what df[3] does??

Comment: Using `urllib.requests` did actually just performed the process twice as `.read_html` does that :) so there is no need for that step

Comment: Explanation of why I downvoted: I rarely downvote answers. I usually dislike downvotes without explanation to where I could improve. So here is mine. You added extra and unused codes `from urllib.request import urlopen, Request


   url = "http://goldpricez.com/gold/history/lkr/years-3"

   req = Request(url=url)
   html = urlopen(req).read()` all these is not used. df[3] would work if all that is deleted. ;) that is why. Hope you understand  :)

Comment: @ThejithaAnjana df[3] prints the fourth dataframe of from the dataframes list.

Comment: As for now, it's the `df[1]` element, this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use BeautifulSoup for this the below code works perfectly

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://goldpricez.com/gold/history/lkr/years-3"
r = requests.get(url)
s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
data = s.find_all("td")
data = data[11:]
for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
    print(data[i].text.strip(), "      ", data[i+1].text.strip())
```

This other advantage of using BeautifulSoup is that it is way faster that your code

Comment: `.read_html` uses bs4 under the hood ;) `flavor : str or None, container of strings
The parsing engine to use. ‘bs4’ and ‘html5lib’ are synonymous with each other, they are both there for backwards compatibility. The default of None tries to use lxml to parse and if that fails it falls back on bs4 + html5lib.`

Answer (score 0):

The way you used `.read_html` will return a list of all tables. Your table is at index 3

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "http://goldpricez.com/gold/history/lkr/years-3"

df = pd.read_html(url)[3]

print(df)
```

`.read_html` makes a call to the URL, and uses BeautifulSoup to parse the response under the hood. You can change the parse, the name of the table, pass header as you would in `.read_csv`. Check [.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) for more details.

For speed, you can use `lxml` e.g. `pd.read_html(url, flavor='lxml')[3]`. By default, `html5lib`, which is the second slowest, is used. Another flavor is `html.parser`. It is the slowest of them all.