# Only crawler the first page and save detailed contents as dataframe in Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to loop pages, crawler and save detailed contents from [this link](http://www.jscq.com.cn/dsf/zc/cjgg/index.html):

Based on the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66671291/loop-pages-and-save-detailed-contents-as-dataframe-in-python), I've modified the code to:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = "http://www.jscq.com.cn/dsf/zc/cjgg"

def get_main_urls() -> list:
    start_url = f"{BASE_URL}/index.html"
    return [start_url] + [f"{BASE_URL}/index_{i}.html" for i in range(1, 6)]


def get_follow_urls(urls: list, session: requests.Session()) -> iter:
    for url in urls[:1]:  # remove [:1] to scrape all the pages
        body = session.get(url).content
        s = BeautifulSoup(body, "lxml").find_all("td", {"width": "60%"})
        yield from [f"{BASE_URL}{a.find('a')['href'][1:]}" for a in s]

updated_df = pd.DataFrame()

with requests.Session() as connection_session:  # reuse your connection!
    for follow_url in get_follow_urls(get_main_urls(), connection_session):
        key = follow_url.rsplit("/")[-1].replace(".html", "")
        # print(f"Fetching data for {key}...")
        dfs = pd.read_html(
            connection_session.get(follow_url).content.decode("utf-8"),
            flavor="bs4")
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710903/pd-read-html-imports-a-list-rather-than-a-dataframe
        for df in dfs:
            # df = dfs[0].T
            df = dfs[0].T.iloc[1:, :].copy()
            updated_df = updated_df.append(df)
            print(updated_df)
    
    cols = ['项目编号', '转让/出租标的名称', '转让方/出租方名称', '转让标的评估价/年租金评估价（元）', 
            '转让底价/年租金底价（元）', '受让方/承租方名称', '成交价/成交年租金（元）', '成交日期']
    updated_df.columns = cols
    updated_df.to_excel('./data.xlsx', index = False)
```

But it only successfully crawler the first page, how could I crawler all the pages and also add `url` column? Thanks.

Comment: make an initial request to requests and bs4 and extract `.pagenav_span font font` to get number of pages then loop generating the new url to insert current page number into url? `f'http://www.jscq.com.cn/dsf/zc/cjgg/index_{page_number}.html'`

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand your question, could you pls paste your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? This processes all the urls and dumps a list of dataframes to a single excel file.

Here's how:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_URL = "http://www.jscq.com.cn/dsf/zc/cjgg"
COLUMNS = [
    '项目编号', '转让/出租标的名称', '转让方/出租方名称',
    '转让标的评估价/年租金评估价（元）', '转让底价/年租金底价（元）',
    '受让方/承租方名称', '成交价/成交年租金（元）', '成交日期', 'URL'
]


def get_main_urls() -> list:
    start_url = f"{BASE_URL}/index.html"
    return [start_url] + [f"{BASE_URL}/index_{i}.html" for i in range(1, 6)]


def get_follow_urls(urls: list, session: requests.Session()) -> iter:
    for url in urls:
        body = session.get(url).content
        s = BeautifulSoup(body, "lxml").find_all("td", {"width": "60%"})
        yield from [f"{BASE_URL}{a.find('a')['href'][1:]}" for a in s]


def post_process(list_of_dataframes: list, source_url: str) -> pd.DataFrame():
    temp_df = list_of_dataframes[0]
    temp_df = temp_df.append(
        pd.Series(["URL", source_url], index=temp_df.columns),
        ignore_index=True,
    )
    return temp_df.T.iloc[1:, :].copy()


def dump_to_excel(post_processed_dfs: list):
    df = pd.concat(post_processed_dfs)
    df.columns = COLUMNS
    df.to_excel("scraped_data.xlsx", index=False)


processed_dfs = []
with requests.Session() as connection_session:  # reuse your connection!
    for follow_url in get_follow_urls(get_main_urls(), connection_session):
        key = follow_url.rsplit("/")[-1].replace(".html", "")
        print(f"Fetching data for {key}...")
        df_list = pd.read_html(
            connection_session.get(follow_url).content.decode("utf-8"),
            flavor="bs4",
        )
        processed_dfs.append(post_process(df_list, follow_url))
    dump_to_excel(processed_dfs)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly, could we add a `url` column to save the link for each item? For example: http://www.jscq.com.cn/dsf/zc/cjgg/202103/t20210311_30347.html, etc.

Comment: Sure, that can be done. What should the column be named in the target language (Chinese, right?)?

Comment: Btw, it's seems not easy to understand your code, could you pls add explanations?

Comment: Using `url_link` as column name is ok.

Comment: @ahbon Check the updated answer. I'll add comment later. Meanwhile, study the code and try to figure it out on your own. :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. PS. You can always [buy me a coffee](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/baduker) if you feel like saying thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230120/discussion-between-ahbon-and-baduker).